# MR_importFromObject method is not working in XCode7.1 beta (Swift 2.0)

Tags: ios, swift2, magicalrecord, xcode7

I want to create entity from dictionary using MR_ImportFromObject method.
It worked before I update Xcode 6 to 7. 
But when I use Xcode7, ImportFromObject method is not working.
Every call that method, willImport Delegate method is not called and application is crashed.

But ImportFromArray method is working very well.

Here is error message. I think the points are "swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC" and "value type is not bridged to Objective-C".

> libswiftCore.dylib`swift_bridgeNonVerbatimFromObjectiveC:
>       0x1060d4d50 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
>       0x1060d4d51 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
>       0x1060d4d54 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
>       0x1060d4d56 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
>       0x1060d4d58 <+8>:   pushq  %r12
>       0x1060d4d5a <+10>:  pushq  %rbx
>       0x1060d4d5b <+11>:  movq   %rdx, %r14
>       0x1060d4d5e <+14>:  movq   %rsi, %rbx
>       0x1060d4d61 <+17>:  movq   %rdi, %r15
>       0x1060d4d64 <+20>:  leaq   0x54a15(%rip), %rsi       ; _TMpSs21_ObjectiveCBridgeable
>       0x1060d4d6b <+27>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
>       0x1060d4d6e <+30>:  callq  0x1060d4610               ; swift_conformsToProtocol
>       0x1060d4d73 <+35>:  movq   %rax, %r12
>       0x1060d4d76 <+38>:  testq  %r12, %r12
>       0x1060d4d79 <+41>:  je     0x1060d4dc9               ; <+121>
>       0x1060d4d7b <+43>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
>       0x1060d4d7e <+46>:  movq   %rbx, %rsi
>       0x1060d4d81 <+49>:  callq  *0x8(%r12)
>       0x1060d4d86 <+54>:  testb  %al, %al
>       0x1060d4d88 <+56>:  je     0x1060d4e49               ; <+249>
>       0x1060d4d8e <+62>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
>       0x1060d4d91 <+65>:  movq   %rbx, %rsi
>       0x1060d4d94 <+68>:  callq  *0x10(%r12)
>       0x1060d4d99 <+73>:  movq   %r15, %rdi
>       0x1060d4d9c <+76>:  movq   %rax, %rsi
>       0x1060d4d9f <+79>:  callq  0x1060d2100               ; swift_dynamicCastUnknownClass
>       0x1060d4da4 <+84>:  testq  %rax, %rax
>       0x1060d4da7 <+87>:  je     0x1060d4e49               ; <+249>
>       0x1060d4dad <+93>:  movq   0x20(%r12), %r8
>       0x1060d4db2 <+98>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
>       0x1060d4db5 <+101>: movq   %r14, %rsi
>       0x1060d4db8 <+104>: movq   %rbx, %rdx
>       0x1060d4dbb <+107>: movq   %rbx, %rcx
>       0x1060d4dbe <+110>: popq   %rbx
>       0x1060d4dbf <+111>: popq   %r12
>       0x1060d4dc1 <+113>: popq   %r14
>       0x1060d4dc3 <+115>: popq   %r15
>       0x1060d4dc5 <+117>: popq   %rbp
>       0x1060d4dc6 <+118>: jmpq   *%r8
>       0x1060d4dc9 <+121>: movq   (%rbx), %rcx
>       0x1060d4dcc <+124>: xorl   %eax, %eax
>       0x1060d4dce <+126>: cmpq   $0x80, %rcx
>       0x1060d4dd5 <+133>: cmovbeq %rcx, %rax
>       0x1060d4dd9 <+137>: cmpq   $0xf, %rax
>       0x1060d4ddd <+141>: jne    0x1060d4df1               ; <+161>
>       0x1060d4ddf <+143>: testl  $0x80ffffff, 0x10(%rbx)
>       0x1060d4de6 <+150>: jne    0x1060d4e49               ; <+249>
>       0x1060d4de8 <+152>: leaq   0x54959(%rip), %r12       ; protocol witness table for Swift._BridgeableMetatype : Swift._ObjectiveCBridgeable in Swift
>       0x1060d4def <+159>: jmp    0x1060d4d7b               ; <+43>
>       0x1060d4df1 <+161>: cmpq   $0xd, %rax
>       0x1060d4df5 <+165>: jne    0x1060d4e49               ; <+249>
>       0x1060d4df7 <+167>: movq   0x8(%rbx), %rax
>       0x1060d4dfb <+171>: movq   (%rax), %rcx
>       0x1060d4dfe <+174>: xorl   %eax, %eax
>       0x1060d4e00 <+176>: cmpq   $0x80, %rcx
>       0x1060d4e07 <+183>: cmovbeq %rcx, %rax
>       0x1060d4e0b <+187>: leaq   0x54936(%rip), %r12       ; protocol witness table for Swift._BridgeableMetatype : Swift._ObjectiveCBridgeable in Swift
>       0x1060d4e12 <+194>: cmpq   $0x3f, %rax
>       0x1060d4e16 <+198>: jg     0x1060d4e33               ; <+227>
>       0x1060d4e18 <+200>: cmpq   $0xf, %rax
>       0x1060d4e1c <+204>: ja     0x1060d4d7b               ; <+43>
>       0x1060d4e22 <+210>: movl   $0xb706, %ecx
>       0x1060d4e27 <+215>: btq    %rax, %rcx
>       0x1060d4e2b <+219>: jae    0x1060d4d7b               ; <+43>
>       0x1060d4e31 <+225>: jmp    0x1060d4e49               ; <+249>
>       0x1060d4e33 <+227>: leaq   -0x40(%rax), %rcx
>       0x1060d4e37 <+231>: cmpq   $0x2, %rcx
>       0x1060d4e3b <+235>: jb     0x1060d4e49               ; <+249>
>       0x1060d4e3d <+237>: cmpq   $0x80, %rax
>       0x1060d4e43 <+243>: jne    0x1060d4d7b               ; <+43>
>       0x1060d4e49 <+249>: leaq   0x4467e(%rip), %rax       ; "value type is not bridged to Objective-C"
>       0x1060d4e50 <+256>: movq   %rax, 0x86561(%rip)       ; gCRAnnotations + 8
>       0x1060d4e57 <+263>: int3
>   ->  0x1060d4e58 <+264>: nopl   (%rax,%rax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the MagicalRecord MR_importFromObject Library for now from

```
id value = [objectData MR_valueForAttribute:primaryAttribute];

if (primaryAttribute != nil)
 {
      managedObject = [self MR_findFirstByAttribute:[primaryAttribute name] withValue:value inContext:context];
 }
```

to

```
 if (primaryAttribute != nil)
 {
   id value = [objectData MR_valueForAttribute:primaryAttribute];
            managedObject = [self MR_findFirstByAttribute:[primaryAttribute name] withValue:value inContext:context];
 }
```

You can probably put this in a category or extension (swift) on NSManagedObject and use that until MagicalRecord fixes this.  That's what I'll do.  This fixed this crash for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the swift compiler optimizations. We had a similar crash unrelated to magical record that was fixed by changing that setting.